# Why are there ghost/random accounts in salesforce when calling this beatbox API?

Tags: python, salesforce, beatbox

I am using the beatbox API to print out all my accounts on my dummy Salesforce account. The only account I've created on my dummy account is "Sally", I have no idea where the rest came from. These accounts circled in red don't even show on my dummy salesforce account. How do I get rid of these ghost accounts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those accounts came with the SF org. They were there before you created the Sally account.

You can get rid of them by deleting them just like with any other records in your org.